# Will I be able to cook my mac & cheese until it's brown if my cheese sauce is thick

Tags: baking, cheese

I found this recipe that requires thick cheese sauce the reviews was good but her mac & cheese was light and I was wondering will I be able to cook my mac & cheese until it browns or if I'm able to brown thick cheese sauce

Comment: Hi Breanna! Welcome to Seasoned Advice.  I don't think the thickness will be the factor in browning. There might be something else different about the recipe. Posting the full recipe & method would help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

I've made many varieties of mac and cheese, both thick and thin so I'm confident in saying that browning is a matter of preference. There's no reason you can't brown the top more if you like.  Use a higher oven temperature or you can put finish it under a grill/broiler to give it more color. I find a layer of breadcrumbs mixed with cheese browns well on mac and cheese.